# consulta sql error al convertir en tipo time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008-r2

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,(DATEDIFF(HOUR,[Hora Salida],[Registro Salida]))),2) + ':' + LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,[Hora Salida],[Registro Salida])),2) + ':00')
```

pero cuando intento ejecutarla me lanza el siguiente error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

lo que quiero es que me una la hora y los minutos pero me lanza el error antes mencionado, ayuda

Comment: Cuál es el resultado esperado?, qué tipo de datos son `[Hora Salida]` y `[Registro Salida]`?, qué necesitas hacer?

Comment: @Lamak estos campos contienen una hora especifica y otra que es la hora en que se registro la salida se espera la resta de esos campos pero que al final salga en tipo TIME

Comment: Pero cuál es el tipo de datos de esas columnas?

Comment: @Lamak tipo TIME

Comment: @Lamak lo que pasa es que ese campo lo obtuve de una converción de un datetime a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en tu consulta.

Primero que todo, debes entender cómo funciona `DATEDIFF`. En tu código estás tratando de concatenar `DATEDIFF(HOUR,...` con `DATEDIFF(MINUTE...`, pero esto te traería resultados incorrectos en muchos casos. Por ejemplo, si la hora de inicio es `09:55` y la hora de fin es `10:06`, `DATEDIFF(HOUR,...` entregará `1` a pesar que no haya pasado una hora; esto es porque un tiempo era a las 9 y el otro a las 10.

Otro problema que tienes es usar `VARCHAR` sin explicitar el largo que quieres; siempre debes poner la longitud como parámetro (`VARCHAR(20)` por ejemplo), sino vas a encontrarte con resultados inesperados.

Dicho todo lo anterior, el código podría ser simplemente el siguiente:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time,DATEADD(MILLISECOND,DATEDIFF(SECOND,[Hora Salida],[Registro Salida])*1000,0),114)
```

Comment: @lamark pero tengo una pregunta quiero convertir esa cadena ejemplo me entrega 15:35:21.000 pero quiero que sea 3:35:21.000

Comment: pero si estás midiendo diferencias de tiempo, no es lo mismo que ver la hora. 15 horas con 35 minutos de diferencia de tiempo no es lo mismo que las 15:35?....

Comment: @lamark pero lo que te indico es lo siguiente si ejemplo 7:00:00 a 15:35 quiero saber la cantidad de horas que hay en ese intervalo como lo haria, esa es mi duda, porque se supone que hay 8:35 horas trabajadas

Comment: Y eso es lo que este código te estaría entregando....lo probaste?

Comment: @lamark si pero me devuelve las 15:35 que deberia ser 8:35 intervalo y lo que quiero es lo que te especifique

Comment: sorry, no entiendo tu comentario. Si ejecuto el código que puse con las horas que dices, me entrega `8:35`. [Acá hay un demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3682824de5ed2d8893bf1e9947bb2d8c)

Comment: @lamark lo que pasa es que en [Registro Salida] es de 24 por lo cual entenderas que si lo ejecuto con el datediff me saldrá 15:35 por que hay un campo que es 12 horas

Comment: Pero así no funciona datediff....puedes mostrar datos de ejemplo al menos?, porque el código está funcionando correctamente

Comment: @lamark disculpa me funciono lo que pasa era que estaba realizando algo mal, muchas gracias